# how to bind function in a dynamically html returned in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Recently I was developing a function and I need to add a function to a dynamically generated HTML via ajax. The code looks like this:

```
$.ajax(
    'success': function(data){
        //do sth
        a.html(res);
        $(document).on('hover',sth in res,function(){
             console.log(1)
             $(this).toggleClass('classA').toggleClass('classB');
        })
    }
)
```

It doesn't seem to work since `console.log()` doesn't print anything. Is there any problem in the binding process? I changed hover to click, mousein, etc, and none of them seem to work. Other functions in the ajax call work fine.

Comment: What is `sth in res`?

Comment: Looks like OP inserted garbage inputs while thinking that the focus was elsewhere :)

Comment: sth in res is a class name in the res string, like '.classA'

Comment: I didn't see the relationship between your question and the posted code. To add a function to a raw html you need to eval those functions (obviously inside a script tag).

Comment: If you use event delegation, you don't need to do it in the `success` function, you can do it when the page is first loaded. If you do the binding in the success function, you can use ordinary event binding since you've already added the element to the DOM.

Comment: Your code works if you change to click. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991316/why-hover-does-not-work-in-delegated-event-handlers for why hover can't be delegated.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/zqw6qwkb/6/ for working demo.

Answer (score 0):

When the html is added dynamically, [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is convenient, in your case you may attach event listener something like-

```
$( document ).on( "click", "sth in res", function( event ) { //Give proper selector in place of sth in res
    console.log(1)
    $(this).toggleClass('classA').toggleClass('classB');
});
```

Also, you might want to put the listener code out of the ajax `success` delegate rather in `$( document ).ready(function() {});`method.

Please see that `sth in res` class name will refer to three different `tag` names, not a single class. If u want to select an element that has all the three classes at the same time then the selector will be `.sth.in.res` -

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".sth.in.res", function( event ) { //Give proper selector in place of sth in res
    console.log(1)
    $(this).toggleClass('classA').toggleClass('classB');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation will take care of this for you. The non-delegated approach that is not working for you is (which is what you do not want):

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){ ... });
```

When adding new elements to the DOM dynamically, you can achieve event delegation using the following:

```
$(document).on('click','selector',function(){ ... });
```

Here are some links to help get you started with learning more:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

[jquery Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035809/jquery-event-delegation)